# what is the correct name for model class in java

Tags: java

I am going to create a model class in my project module. But I am confused what to call my package name for the below type of classes.

I don't have to serialize the object to any other stream.

I just have to read XML file and verify its data.

my model class would be like this

```
public class ModelClassName {

  //private variables

  //setters

  //getters

}
```

Comment: I have always made mine with `<ViewName>Data.java`

Comment: This is entirely subjective. Name it whatever makes the most sense to you in your context and obeys whatever naming conventions, if any, you've been given.

Comment: I usually have these classes in their own package with a name like `model`

Comment: In addition to previous - entity also normal.

Comment: ok thanks everyone,i am going to make it model. But I read somewhere "model" is former name for dtos but mine is not dto

Answer (score 1):

You better pay additional attention to package name, and include 'domain' or 'model' in there.

Comment: Why should domain or model be included in the package name?

Comment: "*You form a unique package name by first having (or belonging to an organization) an Internet domain name, such as `sun.com`. You then reverse this name, component by component, to obtain, in this example, `com.sun`, and use this as a prefix for your package names, using a convention developed within your organization to further administer package names/*" [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=JLS+7.7+Unique+Package+Names&source=bl&ots=Se7DblPgiC&sig=od4YCSTVTwianTq6m1yAnaGUlBA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v-rvUqj-O8r4rQf1woGwAQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: ***Packages:** The prefix of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase ASCII letters and should be one of the top-level domain names, currently `com`, `edu`, `gov`, `mil`, `net`, `org`, or one of the English two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard 3166, 1981.

Subsequent components of the package name vary according to an organization's own internal naming conventions. Such conventions might specify that certain directory name components be division, department, project, machine, or login names.*

Comment: [Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)